# how to build php mvc using ajax like helper

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm building  a small app or mvc web application and i need your advice. the problem is to post or get request or response from database and i don't have  idea how to start. maybe it not clear but that all can i explain in English.
ex:

```
class myClassName{
    public function my_function_class(){
        // here is my function ...
        if(isset($_POST['my_query']){
                //here is my query from database
                return $my_query;
            }
}
```

the thning that it's not clear is how to do this connection betweeen usin session token

Comment: i don't know if i can comment my question, i have read on some books like Beginning Ajax with PHP By Lee Babin, but the thig is to hade my class file or more secure

Comment: Are you actually hitting any errors, or are you looking for folks to  do the work for you?

Comment: @Zarathuztra thank you to replay fast. but i'm realy i didn't use or try any thing at this time, i have use ajax before but was just base to start now im looking for some advice for better use.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Zarathuztra i need or look how to send request by using POST method to ajax or jquery script, my structur look like this: my root have many folders app is where is my app, view, models, libs my autoload file is locate on app/configs/autoload.php soo, i need help on when the post call or better send to my calss locate on libs/ajaxs.php can get response. i know it dificult to understand, but is i all i can explain.